# kubernetes: Proactively trigger nodes' upscaling before rollout

Tags: kubernetes

When performing a new Rollout via the Rolling Upgrade strategy, I have found out that the main bottleneck in terms of duration is the creation of new nodes (by the Cluster Autoscaler) needed to accommodate for the simultaneous presence of old and new pods.

Although tweaking a bit `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` and `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxSurge` values can mitigate the side effects a bit, I see that if I proactively (and manually for the time being) spin up new nodes, the time of the new rollout reduces dramatically.

Are there any off-the-self tools that perform this kind of Tasks?

If not, any recommended strategy to go about this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the cluster autoscaler is just acting on "simple" resource requests, such as CPU and memory, you could launch a couple of "warm-up" Pods at the beginning of your CI process, which will give the autoscaler a "head's up" that a new deployment is coming very soon.

Something like `kubectl run expensive-sleep --image=busybox:latest --requests=memory=32Gi --restart=Never -- sleep 300` which would poke the autoscaler, then the placeholder Pod would exit, but the autoscaler usually does not scale Nodes down immediately, so you would have some freshly provisioned Nodes waiting for the actual rollout of your Deployment.

If the autoscaler is making more complicated decisions, such as GPUs, taints/tolerations, availability zones and whathaveyou, then the trick may require more than just a `kubectl run`, but I believe the underlying idea is plausible